# Difference between 2 hours Jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime, date-difference

Hy everyone ! I found this script for a project of my http://jsfiddle.net/diode/nuv7t/5/ it's make Difference betweeen 2 hours but i need to define these 2 vars

```
var start_actual_time  =  "01/17/2012 11:20";
var end_actual_time    =  "01/18/2012 12:25";
```

Like this :

```
var start_actual_time  =  "input#start";
var end_actual_time    =  "input#end";
```

and the difference to write to a new input #result

Here is what i try: http://jsfiddle.net/UmwXW/

If someone can help me, Thank you.

Comment: Be careful of culture-specific parsing.  For example, if you have "01/04/2012", it could be parsed as either January 4th, or April 1st.  The locale of the browser will determine which it follows.  For more consistent parsing, use an ISO8601 formatted input such as `2012-01-17T11:20` in browsers that support it, or use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse using an explicit format string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/UmwXW/1/

```
var start_actual_time = $("#start").val();
var end_actual_time = $("#end").val();

start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

var diff = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;

var diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds / 3600);
var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds % 3600) / 60;

var formatted = ((HH < 10) ? ("0" + HH) : HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10) ? ("0" + MM) : MM)
$('#result').val(formatted);
```

Comment: The date format in the above example is mm-dd-YYYY. I am using bootstap datetime picker and I want date format as dd-mm-YYYY. How this will work for this format. When I select first_date as 01-10-2015 18:00 and second_date as 02-10-2015 18:37. It gives (second_date - first_date) as 744:37.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's my final code with keyup function. Thanks pXL.

```
$("#end").keyup(function () {


var start_actual_time = $("#start").val();
    var end_actual_time = $("#end").val();

    start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
    end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

    var diff = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;

    var diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
    var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds / 3600);
    var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds % 3600) / 60;

    var formatted = ((HH < 10) ? ("0" + HH) : HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10) ? ("0" + MM) : MM)
   $('#result').val(formatted);

      }).keyup();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmwXW/2/

Comment: The date format in the above example is mm-dd-YYYY. I am using bootstap datetime picker and I want date format as  dd-mm-YYYY. How this will work for this format. When I select first_date as 01-10-2015 18:00 and second_date as 02-10-2015 18:37. It gives (second_date - first_date) as 744:37.